# What is this character?

Tags: orthography

I was reading a book and I couldn't figure out what character this is:

> [image]

What is this character?

Comment: It seems you have trouble identifying kana in different fonts. A good site to practice recognizing various different types of fonts is [realkana.com](http://www.realkana.com/). In the Katakana and Hiragana tabs you can select which kana you want to practice (there's a select all button at the bottom), and in the Options tab you can select which fonts you want to practice. I would recommend selecting all fonts except the one right in the middle, or remove some fonts types you think you have mastered already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the hiragana だ, which is pronounced as *da*. You should keep [a hiragana table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hiragana#Table_of_hiragana) and  [a katakana table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Katakana#Table_of_katakana) nearby if you are just starting out.

Comment: hm I guessed that too, but it seemed quite different, thanks nonetheless